# Android Thread in Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I need to write thread in service . But I'm not sure how to do this exactly. There must be more than one thread. 
Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You start a thread in a service the same way you start a thread in anything.  Either use Java threads, timers, or async task.

Java threads are usually started like so:

```
private Thread yourThread;
private NewRunnable yourRunnable;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
   ... code...
   yourThread = new Thread(yourRunnable);
   ... code...
}

private final class NewRunnable extends Runnable
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
     ... Code here will be run in new thread....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way works great.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Servicio extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initialize();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void initialize(){
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your code ......

            }
        });
        th.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get The context in the Service and Use AsyncTask to create another Thread... Or you can also do

```
new Thrad(){
public void Run(){
//your implementation..
}
}
```